# persian font on javafx android

Tags: android, javafx, fonts, javafxports

I've a javafx code which I am able to run on android using jfxmobile plugin. The problem is with persian/arabic characters which are not shown correctly on label/textfield nor other controls.

Without using any custom font, a label with a persian text set on it, shows some cross-square characters instead of the persian text.

If I use a custom font such as Noto Arabic Naskh, the label shows correct characters but in reverse order. For example, the word سلام which means hello in English and is composed of 4 characters (which are س and ل and ا and م) is shown like م.ا.ل.س (without the dots). Note that the showing characters are not still bounded together while they should.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solve the problem by using library to rewrite the text in correct order.

Comment: which library do you propose for such a conversion?

Comment: I had other character related issues, which I solved by including another set of font files in CSS. (In my example, bold & italic were simply not working on iOS.) #edit: and of course you need to set it either globally (CSS again) or on each node where you need it.

Comment: I've also found this open issue around my question https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/84